# MINGW32 GIT client not able to connect Bonobo GIT Server

Tags: git, mingw32, bonobo

I have followed all the steps for installing Bonobo on one of our office servers.

I am able to run the web application both locally on the server and remotely through another system in the office. So that part works well

However -when I try to use MINGW32 git client to clone my repository, I get an authentication failure message when trying to clone a repository.
fatal : Authentication failed for "http://IpAddress:port/Project.git"

username and password is correct since with same credentials I am able to logon to the web application

I use the following command

```
$ git clone http://IPAddress:port/Project.git
```

[image]
How can I resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't want to use Windows Authentication

I had the same issue while deploying Bonobo on a server (Windows 2008 R2, IIS 7).But the same installation of Bonobo was working on my local machine on Windows 8, and the developers were able to connect to my machine and clone the repository. But the whole point was to make it work on a LAN Server . I read somewhere that IIS Authentication can mess this up. I compared my local IIS with the Server IIS and looked into the Authentication feature by selecting the Website. Both had different authentication types enabled/disabled.

Since Windows 8 web app was working, I replicated the IIS web application authentication settings of Windows 8 to the Server 2008 . Image below show the settings that worked for me. I had everything disabled byt Anonymous Authentication

[image]